# in Slick 3.0, how to I get from a query to a case class?

Tags: scala, slick-3.0

I am trying to use Slick for database in a Scala application, and running into some issues (or my misunderstandings) of how to query (find) and convert the result to a case class.

I am not mapping the case class, but the actual values, with the intent of creating the case class on the fly. so, my table is:

```
object Tables {

  class Names(tag: Tag) extends Table[Name](tag, "NAMES") {
    def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
        def first = column[String]("first")
        def middle = column[String]("last")
        def last = column[String]("last")

        def * = (id.?, first, middle.?, last) <> ((Name.apply _).tupled, Name.unapply)
  }

  object NamesQueries {

    lazy val query = TableQuery[Names]

    val findById = Compiled { k: Rep[Long] =>
      query.filter(_.id === k)
    }
  }
}
```

and here is the query:

```
object NamesDAO {

  def insertName(name: Name) {
    NamesQueries.query += name.copy(id = None)
  }

  def findName(nameId: Long) = {
    val q = NamesQueries.findById(nameId)                         // AppliedCompiledFunction[Long, Query[Tables.Names, Tables.Names.TableElementType, Seq],Seq[Tables.Names.TableElementType]]
    val resultSeq = Database.forConfig("schoolme").run(q.result)  // Future[Seq[Tables.Names.TableElementType]]
    val result = resultSeq.map { r =>                             // val result: Future[(Option[Long], String, Option[String], String) => Name]
      val rr = r.map{ name =>                                     // val rr: Seq[(Option[Long], String, Option[String], String) => Name]
        Name.apply _
      }
      rr.head
    }
    result
  }
}
```

however, the findName method seems to return `Future((Option[Long], String, Option[String], String) => Name)` instead of a `Future(Name)`.  What am i doing wrong? Is it just a matter of just using `asInstanceOf[Name]`?

EDIT: expanded findName to smaller chunks with comments for each one, as sap1ens suggested.

Comment: Probably it's worth to split findName method into multiple lines and use explicit types... At least for debugging, it'll be much easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

well, i'll be damned.
following sap1ens comment above, I broke findName to multiple steps (and edited the question). but after that, i went back and gave my val an explicit type, and that worked. see here:

```
  def findName(nameId: Long) = {
    val q = NamesQueries.findById(nameId)                        
    val resultSeq: Future[Seq[Name]] = Database.forConfig("schoolme").run(q.result)  
    val result = resultSeq.map { r =>
      val rr = r.map{ name =>
        name
      }
      rr.head
    }
    result
  }
```

so, type inference was the (/my) culprit this time. remember, remember.

Comment: Just a side note to save a few lines of code: `r.map { name => name }` does actually nothing. You just map a `Seq[Name]` to another `Seq[Name]`. To get only the first result you can write `val result = resultSeq.map(r => r.head)` which can be expressed a little more concise as `val result = resultSeq.map(_.head)`